# Spring Security XML config

Tags: spring, spring-security

is there any way to do the opposite to "access"? Something like "deny".

```
<intercept-url pattern="/nexthome/logout" access="ROLE_USER,ROLE_ADMIN" />
```

And if there isn't, can I do it somehow?
For example:

```
<intercept-url pattern="/nexthome/logout" access="ROLE_USER,ROLE_ADMIN" deny="ROLE_DENY" />
```

In this situation if a user has ROLE_DENY I expect that he won't see /nexthome/logout

Comment: Use expression instead of just checking the roles you can write fairly complex security rules if you like with those.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Enable expressions:

```xml
<http use-expressions="true">
```

Allow if *USER* or *ADMIN* but not if *DENY*.

```
<intercept-url pattern="/nexthome/logout" access="(hasRole('USER') or hasRole('ADMIN')) and !hasRole('DENY')">
```